# Search for a location by geographic coordinate in instagram api

Tags: geocoding, instagram-api

Made instagram api request to search for locations by latitude and longitude:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=MyTokenHere
```

and it returns empty array:

```
 {"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

My access token is set for public_content scope. Also, in the Instagram documentation it says that sandbox is a "fully functional environment" and I did not see anything about limiting the search by geocode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sandbox mode, you will only get posts from you and your sandbox users.

Search at a coordinate where you have posted a photo and then API response will have just that post. Once you go live, you will see all posts for all users.

> Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from
>   each sandbox user